# Unable to Change Critical Battery Action through dconf editor : Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: power-management, battery, gnome-power-manager

I have an ubuntu gnome 16.04 which is upgraded from 14.04. I want to shut down my machine when the battery reaches its critical level.  This was configured through dconf editor and was working fine until the upgrade.

Now after the upgrade, no matter whatever I set in dconf-editor, the system is still going to suspend mode on low battery.

This is my settings[image: power settings]

I have noticed that when I am executing `upower --dump` , I am getting the following at the end.

```
Daemon:
daemon-version:  0.99.4
on-battery:      no
lid-is-closed:   no
lid-is-present:  yes
critical-action: HybridSleep
```

Here, critical-action is shown as something different. How should I fix this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same problem here!

I'm not very familiar with the topic, but tooking for UPower's configuration files I found that the critical-action is setup in `/etc/UPower/UPower.conf`

There you can change the corresponding key to `CriticalPowerAction=PowerOff` and then it should work.

You may also want to check through the other keys set in your UPower.conf file. In my case for instance they were all *not* synchronized with dconf: no idea why!